# Access denied MySQL (with Cloud9)

Tags: mysql

I have pulled an existing project and am trying to get it to run locally (in [Cloud9 IDE](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mysql/1718)). However, I'm running into problems with connecting with the MySQL db.

There are some environment variables I believe to have set correctly. The password is kept empty, following the Cloud9 instructions.
I used `mysql -u root -p` and can then successfully access the MySQL db without submitting a password.

```
DB_NAME=c9
DB_USER=$C9_USER
DB_PASS=
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
```

When I now run `npm run rollback` or `npm run migrate` or anything else with the database, I receive an error:

> Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user
>   '$C9_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I then replaced `$C9_USER` in the environment variables with `root`, and ran `npm run migrate`. This time it worked and it didn't produce an error.

But I'm new to all this and not really sure if it is actually okay what I did. According to the Cloud9 manual I should be working with `$C9_USER`, so why is that not working for me? Also when I now run `npm run rollback` I now get another error (but maybe unrelated?):

> Error: ER_ERROR_ON_RENAME: Error on rename of './c9/#sql-1827_4a' to
>   './c9/sent_emails' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. When I replace $C9_USER with the actual username, it works. The Cloud9 manual seems to suggest otherwise, but I needed to enter the actual values and not refer to the environment variable.